# Descriptive statistics of time variables

Tags: r, time-series

I want to compute simple descriptive statistics (mean, etc) of times when people go to bed. I ran into two problems. The original data comes from an Excel file in which just the time that people went to bed, were typed in - in 24 hrs format. My problem is that r so far doesn't recognizes if people went to bed at 1.00 am the next day. Meaning that a person who went to bed at 10 pm is 3 hrs apart from the one at 1.00 am (and not 21 hrs).

In my dataframe the variable `in_bed` is a `POSIXct` format so I thought to apply an if-function telling that if the time is before 12:00 than I want to add 24 hrs.

My function is:

```
Patr$in_bed <- if(Patr$in_bed <= ) {
  Patr$in_bed + 24*60*60
}
```

My data frame looks like this

```
                        in_bed 
1          1899-12-30 22:13:00
2          1899-12-30 23:44:00
3          1899-12-30 00:08:00
```

If I run my function my variable gets deleted and the following error message gets printed:

```
Warning message:
In if (Patr$in_bed < "1899-12-30 12:00") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What do I do wrong or does anyone has a better idea? And can I run commands such as mean on variables in `POSIXct` format and if not how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you compare Patr$in_bed (vector) and "1899-12-30 12:00" (single value), you get a logical vector. But the IF statement requires a single logical, thus it generates a warning and consider only the first element of the vector.

You can try :

```
Patr$in_bed <- Patr$in_bed + 24*60*60 * (Patr$in_bed < as.POSIXct("1899-12-30 12:00"))
```

Explanations : the comparison in the parenthesis will return a logical vector, which will be converted to integer (0 for FALSE and 1 for TRUE). Then the dates for which the statement is true will have +24*60*60, and the others dates will have +0.

But since the POSIXct format includes the date, I don't see the purpose of adding 24 hrs. For instance,

```
as.POSIXct("1899-12-31 01:00:00") - as.POSIXct("1899-12-30 22:00:00")
```

returns a time difference of 3 hours, not 21.

To answer your last question, yes you can compute the mean of a POSIXct vector, simply with :

```
mean(Patr$in_bed)
```

Hope it helps,
Jérémy